# Can equipped apparel make hurtboxes smaller or bigger?

Tags: splatoon-2

In *Splatoon 2*, I noticed that Angry Rain Boots move my Inkling’s head up a tiny bit in the menu when equipped, compared to other shoes such as the Friendship Bracelet. Can wearing certain shoes, clothes, or hats actually change hurtboxes?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Splatoon Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/3gh4zh/wearing_the_traditional_sandals_makes_your/), it seems that no, the difference is only aesthetic.

> Shoes doesn't make your inkling taller or shorter, it just kinda shortens your inkling's legs. Your height from the ground, and hitbox therefore, are exactly the same as they would be with any other shoe.

Also from [another discussion on Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/3oe5n1/does_certain_gear_like_hats_make_your_hitbox/):

> No, there is no gear in the game that makes your hit box bigger

And since [hairstyles don't change the hitbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSSUMQePtZ0), probably it's the same with shoes.

Comment: If I find more information I'll update this answer, for the moment I can't find anything better

Comment: If you find a satisfactory amount of reliable information, I may give you a bounty.

Comment: There are only opinions, nothing really tested..